# Is DISPLAY:0 shared by multiple docker containers if run Xvfb :0 inside each docker container?

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, xvfb

I need to run the same set of processes inside multiple docker containers and each container process one log. I need to screencast the result of each container. If I run Xvfb :0 inside each container, do they all share Display:0 of host or each uses its own Display:0? If I run ffmpeg inside each container to screencast Display:0, does it get an isolated view of the current container it runs in or the global Display:0? My question is if this Display:0 is shared if Xvfb :0 is started inside each container.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** created displays will not be shared.

As Xvfb is creating a new virtual frame buffer that is a simulated in memory display instance used within the container.

They can be accessed via a socket file that can (usually) be found in `/tmp/.X11-unix/X99`, which is again container specific.

Comment: It's possible to share volumes across containers. I tried sharing the folder you mentioned but that did not seem to be enough.